# Hamilton's Proof of the Tensor Maximum Principle

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

So I have more questions coming from Hamilton's "Three-Manifolds with Positive Ricci Curvature" paper. I'm working in section 9 on Preserving Positive Ricci Curvature, the proof of Theorem 9.1.

I'm really having a hard time writing down the precise details of the bound $|\tilde{N}_{ij}-N_{ij}|\le C|\tilde{M}_{ij}-M_{ij}|$ where $C$ depends only on $max(|\tilde{M}_{ij}|+|M_{ij}|)$. It somehow seems "obvious" from the fact that $N$ is a polynomial, which is the way Hamilton defines it, until you get around to writing down what $N$ looks like in terms of contractions of products of $M$, which is a horrific mess.

I think the best effort I have is choosing normal coordinates at a point such that the metric is $\delta_{ij}$ and $M_{ij}$ is diagonalized, as it's symmetric. Then the norm on the left starts to look like $|Q(\tilde{\lambda_i})-Q(\lambda_i)|$ where $Q$ is a polynomial of $n$ variables, by $Q(\lambda_i)$ I mean $Q(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$, and $\tilde{\lambda_i}=\lambda_i+\epsilon(\delta+t)$ are the perturbed eigenvalues. Then using the mean-value inequality for multivariable functions, for some $0<c<1$ this is $\le |\nabla Q(\lambda_i+c\epsilon(\delta+t))|(\sqrt{n}\epsilon(\delta+t))=|\nabla Q(\lambda_i+c\epsilon(\delta+t))||\tilde{M}_{ij}-M_{ij}|$ taking into account the coordinates in which we are working. I am not sure how this $|\nabla Q|$ would depend on $(|\tilde{M}_{ij}|+|M_{ij}|)$ at this point, if it does at all, or if Hamilton had something different in mind.

I also got stuck again immediately after that, where he concludes, apparently from the estimate above, that $N_{ij}v^iv^j\ge-C\epsilon\delta$ with $C$ depending only on $max|M_{ij}|$. I guess it's not clear to me that an estimate on the norm of a tensor has anything to do with it's action on vectors, given that this action is defined regardless of the presence of a metric.

Any constructive thoughts will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll discuss the bound $|\tilde{N}_{ij}-N_{ij}|\le C|\tilde{M}_{ij}-M_{ij}|$, where $C$ depends only on $max(|\tilde{M}_{ij}|+|M_{ij}|)$.

Fix a point $x\in X$ and coordinates such that at $x$, $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ and $M_{ij}$ is diagonal with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$, which is possible since $M$ is a symmetric $2$-tensor and thus can be orthogonally diagonalized. From the definition of $N$ as a polynomial $p(M,g)$ formed by contracting products of $M$ with $g$, we see that $N$ is diagonal at $x$ and the $i$th diagonal entry is $q_i(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ where the $q_i$ are polynomials. Let $\tilde{\lambda_i}=\lambda_i+\epsilon(\delta+t)$ be the perturbed eigenvalues. We have

$|\tilde{N}_{ij}-N_{ij}|^2=(q_1(\tilde{\lambda_i})-q_1(\lambda_i))^2+\ldots+(q_n(\tilde{\lambda_i})-q_n(\lambda_i))^2$.

Now

$|q_k(\tilde{\lambda_i})-q_k(\lambda_i)|\le |\nabla q_k((1-c)\lambda_i+c\tilde{\lambda_i})||\tilde{\lambda_i}-\lambda_i|=|\nabla q_k((1-c)\lambda_i+c\tilde{\lambda_i})||\tilde M_{ij}-M_{ij}|$

for some $0\le c\le 1$ by the Mean Value Inequality. The quantity $|\nabla q_k|$ is a polynomial since $q_k$ is a polynomial, so just by applying the triangle inequality and using that $c\le 1$, $|\nabla q_k((1-c)\lambda_i+c\tilde{\lambda_i})|$ is bounded by a polynomial in $|\tilde{\lambda_k}|+|\lambda_k|$ where $k$ is the index maximizing $|\tilde{\lambda_k}|+|\lambda_k|$, and $|\tilde{\lambda_k}|+|\lambda_k|$ is straightforwardly bounded by $|\tilde{M}_{ij}|+|M_{ij}|$. Thus

$|\nabla q_k((1-c)\lambda_i+c\tilde{\lambda_i})|\le C_k$, where $C_k$ depends on $max(|\tilde{M}_{ij}|+|M_{ij}|)$.

Then it follows that

$|\tilde{N}_{ij}-N_{ij}|=[(q_1(\tilde{\lambda_i})-q_1(\lambda_i))^2+\ldots+(q_n(\tilde{\lambda_i})-q_n(\lambda_i))^2]^{1/2}\le (C_1+\ldots+C_n)^{1/2}|\tilde M_{ij}-M_{ij}|=C|\tilde M_{ij}-M_{ij}|$.

There's also the claim that $N_{ij}v^iv^j\ge -C\epsilon\delta$ to address. First we need several simple facts which are straightforward to verify.

$\langle T_{i_1\ldots i_a},S_{j_1\ldots j_a}\rangle= T_{i_1\ldots i_a}S^{i_1\ldots i_a}$ where $S_{i_1\ldots i_a}=g_{i_1j_1}\ldots g_{i_aj_a}S^{j_1\ldots j_a}$

$\langle T_{i_1\ldots i_a},T_{j_1\ldots j_a}\rangle=\langle T^{i_1\ldots i_a},T^{j_1\ldots j_a}\rangle$, so in particular $|v|=|v^{\flat}|$

$|T\otimes S|=|T||S|$

From this it then follows that

$|(\tilde{N}_{ij}-N_{ij})v^iv^j|=\langle \tilde{N}-N, v^{\flat}\otimes v^{\flat}\rangle\le |\tilde{N}_{ij}-N_{ij}||v^{\flat}\otimes v^{\flat}|=|\tilde{N}_{ij}-N_{ij}||v^{\flat}|^2=|\tilde{N}_{ij}-N_{ij}||v|^2=|\tilde{N}_{ij}-N_{ij}|\le C|\tilde{M}_{ij}-M_{ij}|=C\epsilon(\delta+t)\sqrt{n}\le 2C\epsilon\delta\sqrt{n}$

since $0\le t\le T$

by using the facts above, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and the bound obtained in the first part.

Then $2C\epsilon\delta\sqrt{n}\ge |(\tilde{N}_{ij}-N_{ij})v^iv^j|\ge (\tilde{N}_{ij}-N_{ij})v^iv^j\ge -N_{ij}v^iv^j$ by the null-eigenvector condition, from which it follows that $N_{ij}v^iv^j\ge -C\epsilon\delta$, where this $C$ is just a constant multiple of our previous $C$ from above.

It is easy to check that $|\tilde{M}|^2=|M|^2+2\epsilon(\delta+t)\langle M,g\rangle +{\epsilon}^2(\delta+t)^2n\le (|M|+2\sqrt{n})^2$ so we can make our constant depend only on $max |M_{ij}|$ by keeping $\epsilon, \delta\le 1$ as Hamilton states.

Answer (score 0):

Just would like to note down some thoughts, despite that this question has already been here for more than six years. Hope that it may be helpful.

Since it is a pointwise estimate, let us fix a point $x\in X$ and choose a local frame $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that $\{e_i(x)\}_{i=1}^n$ is an orthonormal basis for $T_xX$ (e.g. local coordinate frame induced by normal coordinates centered around $x$).

The key point here, in my humble opinion, is that contractions are actually "a kind of matrix product". Thus what Hamilton means is a "polynomial of matrices". Let me explain by examples. Says $\alpha$ is a symmetric $2$-tensor with local expression $\alpha_{ij}$, and $\beta$ is a polynomial of $\alpha$. To be more explicit, let us take $\beta=\alpha^3$; i.e.,
\begin{align}
\beta_{ij}=\alpha_{ik}g^{kl}\alpha_{lm}g^{mp}\alpha_{pj}
\end{align}
Then at point $x$, since $g^{ij}=\delta^{ij}$, the expression is reduced to
\begin{align}
\beta_{ij}=\sum_{k,m=1}^n\alpha_{ik}\alpha_{km}\alpha_{mj}
\end{align}
Notice that the R.H.S. is precisely the $(i,j)$-entry of the (matrix) product of the matrices $(\alpha_{ij})$. I have chosen $\beta$ to be $\alpha^3$ here, but it is not hard to see that this is true for any (nonnegative) power of $\alpha$. This suggests that some linear algebra result may be helpful.

If we let $\tilde{\beta}=\tilde{\alpha}^3$, then
\begin{align}
\tilde{\beta}-\beta=\tilde{\alpha}^3-\alpha^3
\end{align}
The R.H.S. sort of reminds us the elementary algebraic identity
\begin{align}
a^3-b^3=(a^2+ab+b^2)(a-b)
\end{align}
where $a,b$ are numbers, and note that R.H.S. has a factor $a-b$, which resembles what we eventually want in our estimate. However, the identity relies on the fact that multiplication on $\mathbb{R}$ is commutative, a property that is no longer true when $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by the ring of matrices, and so we have to be a little bit more careful. Nevertheless, we still have the following identity: For any matrices $A,B$,
\begin{align}
A^k-B^k=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}A^{k-1-i}(A-B)B^i
\end{align}
Taking (appropriate) norm, we have
\begin{align}
|A^k-B^k|&\leq\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}|A|^{k-1-i}|A-B||B|^i \\
&\leq\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(|A|+|B|)^{k-1-i}(|A|+|B|)^i\right)|A-B| \\
&\leq k(|A|+|B|)^{k-1}|A-B|
\end{align}
Turning back to our tensor, we perform the same calculation and conclude that at point $x$,
\begin{align}
|\tilde{\beta}-\beta|
&\leq 3\left(|\tilde{\alpha}|+|\alpha|\right)^2|\tilde{\alpha}-\alpha| \\
&\leq \underbrace{3\left[\max_X\left(|\tilde{\alpha}|+|\alpha|\right)\right]^2}_{:=C}|\tilde{\alpha}-\alpha| \\
&=C|\tilde{\alpha}-\alpha|
\end{align}
This explains why $C$ depends on $\max_X\left(|\tilde{\alpha}|+|\alpha|\right)$. Now for the general case $|\tilde{N}_{ij}-N_{ij}|$ the idea is the same.